# req.user is undefined, but logging in works fine

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

**Background**

I recognize that this question has been asked a million times, but none of said questions ever fixed my problem. In my apps routes, calling req.user only ever returns undefined, regardless of which route I'm accessing.

My login feature works fine as well, if this helps. I have specific elements of my client change when logged in/not, but req.user returns undefined regardless.

As many have pointed out for similar questions, it's probably a slip-up in the ordering of my middleware,  but I can't for the life of me find it as my ordering is practically copy/pasted from around ~3 different places.

The general layout of my app is one main file, app.js, that sets up my express app and contains all of my routes. All of my routes are places below my middleware setup.

**Relevant app.js Code**

```
// Middleware
// Setup DB Pool and app
var pool = mysql.createPool(db.pool);
var app  = express();

// Setup Handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', exprhbr({defaultLayout: 'index'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Setup body parser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Setup session
app.use(session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
    secret: 'spooky',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Setup passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

...

```
// An example route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let loggedIn = req.isAuthenticated(); // works perfectly
    console.log('user: ', req.user); // always prints "user: undefined"

    res.status(200).render('home', {
        page:     'Home',
        noSearch: true,
        loggedIn: loggedIn,
        user:     req.body.username
    });
});

// My login route
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    if (verify.login(req.body)) {
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            session: true,
            successRedirect: '/user/' + req.body.username,
            failureRedirect: '/login'
        })(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

**Passport**

I initialize passport using:

```
require('./src/passport')(passport);
```

at the top of my file, and said passport file looks like this:

**Relevant passport.js Code**

```
var strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt');
var mysql    = require('mysql');
var db       = require('./database');
var pool     = mysql.createPool(db.pool);

module.exports = (passport) => {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.uid);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((uid, done) => {
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM User WHERE (user_id = ?)', [uid], (err, result) => {
            done(err, {uid: result[0].user_id, username: result[0].username, pass: result[0].password});
        });
    });

    // Setup Passport
    passport.use(new strategy({ usernameField: 'username' }, (username, pass, done) => {
        // Match a user
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM User Where (username = ?)', [username], (err, result) => {
            if (!result.length) return done(null, false, {message: 'Username isn\'t registered'});
            let user = result[0];

            // User was found so decrpt pass
            bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                // User matches
                if (isMatch)
                    return done(null, {uid: user.user_id, username: username, pass: user.password});
                else
                    done(null, false, {message: 'Password doesn\'t match'})
            });
        });
    }));
}
```

Swapping around the ordering of my function declarations does nothing if that helps at all.

Thanks for taking the time to read this long post, and for possibly helping me out!

Comment: Where are your calls to `passport.authenticate()`? If you read the documentation, it clearly calls it out as a requirement to make something as an authenticated route: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/ And have you setup the middleware?

Comment: I updated my post to include my login route, which contains a call to passport.authenticate(). What I read and saw examples of lead me to think I just needed the one call on user logins, and then I can use req.user on various other routes to get connecting user info. Was I wrong in this assumption and actually need to call authenticate on every route, Or do I not understand your question?

Comment: I just ran your code. First of all, Login request didn't work properly on me and redirected to login page. Then i realize there is no passwordField on strategy. I added passwordField. Login worked and redirected to user page. Then i called GET "/" route. It works perfectly and printed user. I don't understand why login request worked on you and not on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands right now, my site logs you out after a few page refreshes, and most of the time, I don't notice this happening.

My problem arose because I was checking req.user for a user that wasn't logged in, thus the only logical thing for it to return was undefined. Because I didn't notice I was logged out, I assumed it printed undefined regardless of a user being logged in.

I fixed this issue by first confirming the existence of a logged in user by checking if req.user exists, and then setting variables accordingly.

Comment: Did you read my comment? Your code from post is worked on me and printed user except one problem!.

Comment: I did, and even tried what you suggested. I don't use the password field anywhere outside of logging in, and it seems to work without that field included in the strategy creation. I honestly have no idea where this inconsistency comes from, but it all worked out in the end so who cares! Thanks for trying to help anyways; much appreciated.